# Spaces around == operator in if tag

Tags: django

**Django 1.11.2**

This works:

```
{% if n == "1" %}
    {{ n }}
{% endif %}
```

This doesn't:

```
{% if n=="1" %}
    {{ n }}
{% endif %}
```

Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /form/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/smartif.py", line 175, in translate_token
    op = OPERATORS[token]
KeyError: 'n=="1"'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/simple_project/home/views.py", line 22, in get
    {"n": n})
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 67, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 21, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 39, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 162, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 136, in find_template
    name, template_dirs=dirs, skip=skip,
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py", line 44, in get_template
    contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 191, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 230, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 515, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 513, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 312, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 515, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 513, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 255, in do_block
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock',))
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 515, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 513, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 968, in do_if
    condition = TemplateIfParser(parser, bits).parse()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 900, in __init__
    super(TemplateIfParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/smartif.py", line 166, in __init__
    mapped_tokens.append(self.translate_token(token))
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/smartif.py", line 177, in translate_token
    return self.create_var(token)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 903, in create_var
    return TemplateLiteral(self.template_parser.compile_filter(value), value)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 600, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/simple_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 700, in __init__
    "from '%s'" % (token[upto:], token))
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '=="1"' from 'n=="1"'
[22/Jun/2017 08:15:21] "GET /form/?n=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 200974
```

Documentation seems to be silent on this.
I have read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#tags
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#operator

Could you tell me why these spaces are that important. I mean that  other spaces are ignored in Django. Like {{ var }} and {{var}}.

If the spaces are important, maybe we should emphasize this in the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because there is a fundamental difference between template tags and variables. Template tags accept parameters, which need to be separated by spaces. Behind the scenes the template tag is deconstructed and the contents are split on every space. Some template tags can accept a varying amount of parameters, but every template tag has its own implementation on how these are used.

You can do this (where you leave the first and last space out)

```
{%if n == "1"%}
```

But not this

```
{% if n=="1" %}
```

Since in the latter case you only have one parameter. The if template tag can in fact accept only 1 parameter, but then it has to be a boolean value: True or False.

Comment: Your answer seems logical. I need some time to think it over. Do you think it could improve the documentation if we mentioned it?

Comment: It's double. For operators like and, or, in and others it is logical that spaces are required, but I agree that it can be a little bit confusing in case of !=, ==, <, ... since many developers are used they can leave spaces out.

Comment: Pardon. What do you mean by double? Does it mean that this is already in the documentation?

Comment: No, it's not documented. I just tried to say that the situation depends on the type of operator. I do think the documentation can be improved by explaining that spaces are always required between template tag parameters.